# Custom Landing page in Magento

Tags: html, magento

I'm new to Magento want to know does this type of design can be done using magneto or a custom landing page ?

http://goo.gl/S1tcys

design without the using of Magento block??

Answer (score 1):

You can do a local.xml update

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="home_main" as="home_main" template="cms/default/home.phtml">
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Create a file named home.phtml in cms/default/

Then add your home page content in there.